# How can I download a file from MongoDB using delphi mongo-delphi-driver.GridFS.pas?

Tags: delphi, mongodb

I'm experimenting with MongoDB and Delphi ([mongo-delphi-driver](https://github.com/gerald-lindsly/mongo-delphi-driver))

While I was able to upload a file using the code at bottom, I'm struggling to download it back from MongoDB to my filesystem.

Does someone has already a code snippet that can show to me?

Thank you all in advance

```
uses
  ...
  MongoDB, MongoBson, GridFS;

...

procedure UploadFile();
const
  LOCAL_FILE_NAME = 'C:\local_file_name'; 
  REMOTE_FILE_NAME = 'remote_file_name';
var
  GridFSStoreFileSuccess: Boolean;
  myGridFS: TGridFS;
begin
  myGridFS := TGridFS.Create(mongo, db);
  try
    GridFSStoreFileSuccess := myGridFS.storeFile(LOCAL_FILE_NAME, REMOTE_FILE_NAME);
    if GridFSStoreFileSuccess then
      ShowMessage('File upload was successful!')
    else
      ShowMessage('File upload was *NOT* successful!');
  finally
    myGridFS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: could you include a code snippet you tried to use to download the file, and the error you got?

Comment: the problem is that I don't have a code snippet since I don't know where to start with Delphi and TFileStreams and File I/O ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I also try to use mongodb with delphi. This is a snippet for your needs

```
var
  GridFSTest : TGridFS;
  p : Pointer;
  stream : TMemoryStream;
  filename : string;
  f : TGridfile;
begin  
  // Create and link TGridFS to 'test' db
  GridFSTest := TGridFS.Create(Mongo,'test');
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  // Find the image file... 
  f := GridFSTest.find('topo gigio.jpg');

  p := AllocMem(f.getLength);
  f.read(p,f.getLength);

  stream.Write(p^,f.getLength);
  stream.Position := 0;

  ClientDataSet1.Close;
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
  ClientDataSet1.Insert;
  TBlobField(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('immagine')).LoadFromStream(stream);
  ClientDataSet1.Post;

//  stream.SaveToFile('c:\a.jpg');

  stream.Free;
  FreeMem(p);
  GridFS.Free;
end;
```